# Java doesn't see my MAIN clause?

Tags: java

Ok, I don't get it.  I have the following code (and YES I know it does nothing):

```
package com.prim.esaa.gui;


import com.jme3.app.SimpleApplication;

public class Sim3DAnimator extends SimpleApplication {


    public static void main( String[] args ) {

    }


    @Override
    public void simpleInitApp() {

    }




}
```

And I get the following error when I try to run it:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/prim/esaa/gui/Sim3DAnimator
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.prim.esaa.gui.Sim3DAnimator
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: com.prim.esaa.gui.Sim3DAnimator. Program will exit.
```

Now if I read this right it is saying there is no main clause but there is a main clause.  What am I missing here?

Comment: I gotta tell you I feel dumb because this should compile and run without errors and do nothing and I can't get this to work.

Comment: Maybe you should define the main class in a manifest file.

Comment: How are you trying to invoke your class?

Comment: The code itself runs fine. Check classpath and build settings. Also check that the file is in the correct folder based on it's package.

Comment: tell us what command line you type to when you get this output, and where you are on your file system and where the class is.

Comment: Try >java com.prim.esaa.gui.Sim3DAnimator

Comment: building on AVD's answer, run his command line from the folder containing the `com` package.

Comment: Are you running it from within JMonkey?

Comment: I am running this in Eclipse.  I will check the class path.

Answer (score 1):

To launch the `Sim3DAnimator`, you must have to specify the package name. Issue the following command from the parent of `com/prim/esaa/gui`.

```
> java com.prim.esaa.gui.Sim3DAnimator
```

PS: Make sure that the class `Sim3DAnimator` is located at `com/prim/esaa/gui` folder.

Comment: Yes, it is in that directory.

Comment: @JesterHawk - Try => In package explorer of eclipse, select the Java class/file (in which the main() method is defined) + Right mouse click + Run As + Java Application.

Comment: I did that and got the same results.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to run this class incorrectly, hence no class found..

have you tried:

placing Sim3DAnimator.class into a directory path such as: C:\EXAMPLE\com\prim\esaa\gui

and then running (from the root):
C:\EXAMPLE> java com.prim.esaa.gui.Sim3DAnimator

Comment: Ok, I tried that and got what looks like the same stack trace.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.prim.esaa.gui.Sim3DAnimator
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: com.prim.esaa.gui.Sim3DAnimator. Program will exit.

Comment: In the whole project, I think it is 60.  I know a lot.  But right now, I just need this one to work even though it is in the project.  I realize it compiles the whole thing.  I was just hoping that it would only work with what it has for imports.

Comment: can you provide the output of 'dir' on the following directory: *\com\prim\esaa\gui?

Comment: .  ..  Sim3DAnimator.java  SimAnalyzerDisplay.java  SimDisplayFrameGrabber.java  SimDisplay.java  SimDisplayPanel.java  SimDisplayParams.java  SimGanttPanel.java  SimHistogramPanel.java

Comment: Is this is in your src directory? What about your bin directory? Are you trying to RUN the application from eclipse?

Comment: @JesterHawk - have you compiled those classes?   The compiled classes are the ones that have to be on the classpath.

Comment: @Matt Jones, yes I am trying to run from Eclipse and that is the workspace/prim/src/com/prim/esaa/gui.  I haven't looked in the bin directory.

Comment: @StephenC, yes I have compiled all the other classes.

Comment: I will add that I have five projects in my Eclipse package viewer thingy.  Only one of the packages compiles and runs.  The other four do not now.  So, I must have changed something when I went in and added the *.jar files to use jMonkey that somehow killed the other projects while only letting the "test" project work.  Any thoughts on what that could be?  Thanks!

Comment: Time to head home for the night.  This will have to wait until tomorrow to fix.  But if you have any ideas I will try them first thing tomorrow evening when I get in.  Thanks Everyone!

Comment: Right click on the class > Run as > Run Configurations. Is the main class defined as Sim3DAnimator? If not, change that to the correct class.

Answer (score 0):

> Now if I read this right it is saying there is no main clause but there is a main clause.

What it is *actually* saying is that it cannot find the **class** whose fully qualified name is "com.prim.esaa.gui.Sim3DAnimator".  In fact, it says this THREE TIMES ... in different ways.

If it could find the class, it would recognize the classes "main" method as an entrypoint, because your main method has the right characteristics.

So why can't it find the class?  Well, it is most likely that you haven't got the classpath right.  For details on how the Java classpath works  and how to set it, refer to this Java manual page - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

Another possibility (based on your comments) is that you haven't compiled the java code.

Comment: I checked and it is in the com.prim.esaa.gui package as a class.  And the com.prim project overall is what is being built and included in the build path in Eclipse.  What could I be missing?

Comment: Ok, the classpath is set in the launcher shell script and set to basically nothing.  Just something for X3D.  Nothing for the project at all.  Is this where it should be?  And if so what should be in there?  If not where else in Eclipse do I set it?

Answer (score 0):

Not the best of solutions. But I closed and deleted all the projects I had in my package explorer.  I then re-checkedout from SVN a clean copy.  I then created the class and it runs fine.  Something got screwy in my build setup and it prevented everything from running.

THANKS!